# Can my program detect whether it's running as a Windows/Systemd service?

Tags: c#, .net, service, systemd

In C#/.NET 6 you can now create a cross-platform service to run as either a Windows service or a Systemd one with something like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .UseSystemd()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); }); }
```

`UseWindowsService` and `UseSystemd` can always be called because they are a noop if they're not actually running in the context of a Windows or Systemd service.  However, is there a way to detect whether they have actually activated (and log a message like "running as Windows service" / "running as Systemd service"), and also detect whether neither have activated, and fall back to running as a console app?